# Breadcrumb libraries (html5/css)

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a library which has some custom breadcrumbs as the following:

[image]

Any idea what I could use to have a result looking as my image (ish).

Comment: With over 1K rep you should know that asking for libraries, frameworks, or other off-site resources is off-topic for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create fast in css like this:

No need library, just adapt my snippet for you with your styles and icons

```js
$('.breadcrumb__item').click(function(){
  $('.breadcrumb__item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.breadcrumb{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.breadcrumb::after{
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  content:'';
}

.breadcrumb__item{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px; 
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.breadcrumb__item span{
  display: block; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.breadcrumb__item.active span{
  background: #fff;
}

.breadcrumb__item.active ~ .breadcrumb__item{
  border-color: grey;
}


.breadcrumb__item.active ~ .breadcrumb__item span{
  display: none;
}

.breadcrumb__item.active::after{
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 999999%;
  background: grey;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  content:'';
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb__item">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb__item active">
    <span>2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb__item">
    <span>3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb__item">
    <span>4</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```